# "Quand Dieu distribua des cerveaux, tu gardas un parapluie"

Tags: expressions, traduction, registre-familier, grec, proverbes

En Grèce on a une expression qui peut être littéralement traduite en français comme suit :

> "Quand Dieu distribua des cerveaux, tu gardas un parapluie".

ou au sens plus figuré

> "Quand Dieu distribua de l'intelligence, tu gardas un parapluie".

Cette expression est utilisée pour des personnes manquant d'intelligence ou pour les personnes qui ont, à un moment donné, répondu de façon complètement stupide à une question ou ont fait quelque chose naïvement.

> Pourquoi t'as fait ça ? Quand Dieu distribua des cerveaux, tu gardas un parapluie.

Quelles expressions françaises rendent des idées similaires ?

Comment: Cette expression est certainement utilisée presque seulement dans la langue parlée en grec ; pourquoi une traduction littérale en français d'un texte de langue parlée passerait-elle à un temps littéraire ? Avez-vous, vous aussi, pris votre parti de remettre le passé simple en vogue ?

Comment: @LPH Je l'ai considéré comme une proverbe ou un dicton:-)! Je ne pensais pas que c'est choquant pour un natif. N'hésitez pas à modifier les temps.

Comment: @LPH En vogue ? Je le comprends pas. Je sais bien sûr que le passé simple est considéré plutôt littéraire. On préfère le passé composé (qui est plus facile:-)!). Mais pour des dictons, proverbes même des tournures humoristiques, qui nous embêcher d'utliser le passé simple même dans un registre familier ?

Comment: Vos répliques constituent plusieurs questions connectées et j'ai commencé à répondre à une partie de ce qui est demandé, mais cela représente beaucoup de texte et seriez-vous suffisamment curieux sur ce sujet  il serait mieux que vous réunissiez ces répliques pour en faire une question normale de sorte que je puisse donner une réponse aussi complète que possible et éventuellement avec des références plus intéressantes.

Comment: @LPH So shall be asked so shall be done :-)! https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/38005/emploi-du-pass%c3%a9-simple-dans-un-registre-familier-est-ce-une-aff%c3%a9terie-est-ce

Comment: _tu portais_ ou _tu tenais_ seraient plus approprié.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Peut-être la réplique de Gabin dans *Le cave se rebiffe* (dialogues de Michel Audiard), ce qui nous donnerait :

- Si la connerie se mesurait, tu servirais de mètre étalon, tu serais à Sèvres.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_ELkQvzaiY

Sèvres étant la ville où le Bureau international des poids et mesures a son siège au pavillon de Breteuil.

Comment: Je ne connaissais pas cette expression, mais pas mal !

Answer (score 4):

J'ai déjà entendu les expressions suivantes pour exprimer la même idée:

1. Lors de la distribution (sous-entendu ou clairement exprimé : d'intelligence / de neurones), tu étais absent(e) ?
2. Au moment de la distribution (d'intelligence / de neurones), le tapis roulant ne s'est pas arrêté ?

Dans le 2ème exemple, c'est comme dans une usine d'embouteillage, avec du travail à la chaîne. Je ne connais pas l'origine exacte de ces expressions populaires, mais je les ai souvent entendues.

Dans la musique, il y a Renaud qui chantait (à propos de son beauf', mais c'est adaptable pour quiconque, bien sur):

- le jour où les cons seront cuisiniers, c'est lui qui préparera les sauces !

ou encore (source inconnue):

- le jour où les cons voleront, tu seras chef d'escadrille.
- il y a des gens un peu bêtes sur les bords, mais chez toi, les bords se touchent !

de [Michel Audiard](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Audiard) (thanks to @cl-r pour la référence):

- quand on mettra les cons sur orbite, t'as pas fini de tourner !

Comment: Ou une variante déjà entendue: " le jour où on a distribué les cerveaux, tu étais au bout de la queue ? "

Comment: Il me semble que l’escadrille (et peut-être le rapprochement des bords) est dans un dialogue d’Audiard :  https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Audiard

Comment: Ton bonheur est ici : https://citations.ouest-france.fr/citation-anonyme/quand-cons-voleront-seras-chef-85972.html

Answer (score 1):

Je n'avais jamais entendu une telle expression, c'est vrai que c'est très parlant, vu comme ça.
Je n'ai pas en tête d'expression française ressemblant de près à la tienne, mais voici une liste d'expressions qui répondent à ta question :

- "Pourquoi t'as fait ça? Tu as laissé ton cerveau à l'entrée."
- "Pourquoi t'as fait ça? Tu es bête comme un âne."
- "Pourquoi t'as fait ça? T'es bête comme tes pieds"

---

Dans le style vulgaire sinon, il y a :

- "Pourquoi t'as fait ça? T'as été fini à la pisse." (argot)

Answer (score 1):

Quelques unes que j'ai parfois lues ou entendues.

Une variante de ce qui a déjà été dit :

- À la distribution des cerveaux, t'étais parti pisser.

Et :

- T'as trouvé ton intelligence dans une pochette surprise.
- Ton intelligence est comme un sucre dans un café : plus on le cherche moins on le trouve.

Une expression relativement fréquente c'est :

- T'es con comme un balai.

Avec sa variante :

- Con comme un manche à balai.

Ou tout simplement :

- Con comme un manche.

Pour l'explication voir sur [expressio](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/con-comme-un-balai.php).

Il doit en exister beaucoup, la moquerie est une chose si facile !

Answer (score 0):

Voici une variante proposée par mon fils (étudiant 5e).

> Si ta capacité à énerver les gens se transformait en jours fériés, tu serais toujours en vacances !

Comment: Excellent ! :-))