# Emploi du passé simple dans un registre familier : est-ce une afféterie ? est-ce choquant ?

Tags: registre-familier, langage-informel, passé-simple

Suite à la question ["Quand Dieu distribua des cerveaux, tu gardas un parapluie"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/37984/quand-dieu-distribua-des-cerveaux-tu-gardas-un-parapluie)
et aux échanges avec LPH

> "Quand Dieu distribua des cerveaux, tu gardas un parapluie".

Évidement c'est une expression pas idiomatique en français ; une traduction littérale. Grâce aux réponses je connais des variantes françaises idiomatiques. La question porte sur l'emploi du passé simple dans un registre familier. Est-ce choquant aux locuteurs natifs ?

Par exemple, dans un commentaire de l'utilisateur LPH on trouve  :

*Cette expression est certainement utilisée presque seulement dans la langue parlée en grec ; pourquoi une traduction littérale en français d'un texte de langue parlée passerait-elle à un temps littéraire ? Avez-vous, vous aussi, pris votre parti de remettre le passé simple en vogue ?*

Moi je l'ai considéré comme une proverbe ou un dicton. Je sais bien sûr que le passé simple est un temps considéré plutôt littéraire. On préfère le passé composé. Mais pour des dictons, proverbes même des tournures humoristiques et ironiques voire des moqueries, qui nous embêche d'utliser le passé simple même dans le français parlé ? Est-ce une afféterie ?

Comment: Dimitris, vous savez que nous sommes plusieurs sur ce site à douter fortement de la qualité de locuteur natif de LPH.  En soi, ce n'est pas un problème, pour peu que le français soit bon.  Malheureusement, ce n'est pas le cas.  Ses réponses doivent donc être prises avec beaucoup de circonspection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il ne survit dans le français parlé, celui de la conversation, que dans des locutions ou des citations, ou bien pour le côté incongru et comique des deuxième et troisième personnes du pluriel (crûtes, revînmes, matâmes, tatâtes…).  On peut le mettre dans le même sac sur ce plan-là que l'imparfait du subjonctif, même si certaines personnes émaillent parfois de ce dernier leurs discours, effet prout-prout garanti :

- *et la lumière fut*, qu'on peut dire à la fin d'une coupure de courant quand la lumière revient.
- *C'est là que les Athéniens s'atteignirent*, ça se gâte.
- *Et le combat cessa faute de combattants*, vers du Cid passé en lieu commun qu'on peut employer quand une dispute ou une altercation se termine.
- *Fut un temps où*…

Il y a certainement bien d'autres exemples.

Les proverbes, eux, se formulent plutôt au présent en français.

Comment: Merci. Mais, pourquoi ne peut-on pas l'employer en français parlé ? Je crois que le passé simple à des valeurs que le passé composé n'en pas. Un temps sans emploi dans le parler est peu vivant, non ?

Comment: @Dimitris La langue parlée est le plus souvent ancrée dans le présent (comme internet, on rencontre peu le passé simple sur internet aussi). Le passé simple est le temps du récit, on peut aussi faire un récit au passé composé pour exprimer la même chose, et le passé composé est plus simple à utiliser pour les Français. Donc on n'en a pas besoin pour s'exprimer au quotidien.

Comment: @Dimitris Le passé simple *est* un temps mort. Il s'apprend à l'école, même pour les Francophones, et pas lors de l'acquisition naturelle de la langue. Tout contraste qu'il peut y avoir dans un texte littéraire entre PS et PC sont une imitation plus ou moins réussie d'un ancien état de la langue, et pour la plupart des locuteurs, surtout si ils ne sont pas professionnels de la langue, il n'y a aucun contraste: ils essayent juste de remplacer leur passés composés habituels par des passés simples lorsqu'on leur demande de rédiger un récit

Answer (score 1):

Ce n'est pas choquant, c'est inhabituel pour quelqu'un qui a une certaine facilité avec le langage, et pas seulement un natif ; je pose la question en raison de mon savoir que d'autres personnes, en particulier sur le présent site, si rarement, emploient le passé simple dans leurs commentaires pour s'exprimer normalement. Il est de ce fait certain que ces personnes visent à normaliser l'usage de ce temps, et celles-ci étant des bilingues connaissant l'anglais, elles cherchent peut-être un équivalent simple et naturel du passé anglais. C'est une attitude courageuse que l'on ne peut pas réprimer, tout au moins je ne me sens pas justifié de le faire : les formes appartiennent au langage et on les apprécie toujours beaucoup dans la lecture ; pourquoi alors les dénigrer lorsque trouvées dans la langue parlée ? C'est très subjectif mais après tout si l'on peut parler un peu plus  comme on écrit tout est pour le mieux dans le meilleur de deux mondes. Néanmoins il faut savoir ceci : on n'emploie plus ce temps dans la langue parlée ; je peux vous assurer que je ne l'ai pas utilisé une seule fois de toute ma vie dans toute ma conversation  et ne l'ai entendu de la bouche d'autrui qu'en quelques rares occasions ([études littéraires](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/indicatif-passe-simple.php), vitalité du passé simple). Il faut savoir de plus qu'il existe une tendance littéraire contemporaine qui annonce la suppression de ce temps même en littérature :  il est remplacé par le passé composé, ce même temps que l'on utilise dans la langue parlée quand le temps plus « logique » devrait être le passé simple (d'où une tendance à écrire un peu plus comme l'on parle et non vice versa, ainsi que la possibilité considérée plus haut le veut). Vous devez donc mieux comprendre maintenant pourquoi j'appelle attitude courageuse celle de trouver possible son emploi dans la langue parlée. C'est une attitude qui peut donner naissance à une nouvelle vogue mais qui peut aussi être la cause d'un désavantage social pour celui qui la partage ; il n'est pas important de savoir si l'on doit appeler cela de l'afféterie ou du gout pour le vieux et le démodé, et comme je le dis plus haut, la motivation pour l'employer serait encore la simplicité de l'usage qui correspond à un besoin auquel l'anglais a une solution sans complexité, ce qui compte finalement c'est toujours la perspective de l'effet négatif sur les gens, qui, eux sont dérangés dans leurs habitudes. Il ne sera pas facile à mon avis d'utiliser ce temps, tout au moins en un début, dans n'importe quelle circonstance (tout comme les temps du subjonctif inusités que certains réintroduisent dans la conversation sur le FSE) ; qui voudra le faire prend donc un risque.

Je ne crois pas que l'on puisse parler d'un proverbe ici : il n'y a aucune vérité générale qui soit énoncée par les mots de cette traduction, ce sont des mots fait pour faire la simple déclaration d'un état de chose; il ne s'agit que d'une façon  particulière de faire une déclaration en cela qu'elle ressort de l'analogie; c'est l'analogie ce en quoi nous sommes intéressés. Donc, il n'est pas question de proverbe ni de dicton dans le sens moderne du mot ; « dicton » a bien signifié « raillerie » mais ce n'est plus utilisé de cette façon (TLFi Vx et fam. ,,Raillerie, mot plaisant et piquant contre quelqu'un``. (Ac. 1798-1878) Le satirique donne à chacun son dicton (Ac. 1798-1878).) ». On n'énonce pas des choses telles que vous les rapportez selon le mode des proverbes, tout au moins pas en français ; examinez soigneusement les réponses à votre question initiale et vous verrez que ce n'est en aucun des multiples cas la forme utilisée, qui est toujours celle de la simple déclaration imputant directement à la personne à qui l'on parle les allégations exprimées (si on ne parle pas de quelqu'un d'autre).

Comment: En général, on ne l’utilise plus à l’oral. À noter qu’au XVIIe siècle, il existait la règle des vingt-quatre heures : un fait s’étant déroulé au-delà de vingt-quatre heures devait se narrer au passé simple. 
Lire la suite sur : https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/indicatif-passe-simple.php (!)

Comment: @Dimitris Çela vient du lien que j'ai fourni dans ma réponse ! Bien sûr, jai lu cette partie.